# lambda function referencing a column value not specified in function

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a situation where I want to use the results of a `groupby` in my training set to fill in results for my test set.

I don't think there's a straight forward way to do this in pandas, so I'm trying use the `apply` method on the column in my test set.

**MY SITUATION:**

I want to use the average values from my `MSZoning` column to infer the missing value for my `LotFrontage` column.

If I use the `groupby` method on my training set I get this:

```
train.groupby('MSZoning')['LotFrontage'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

giving.....

[image]

Now, I want to use these values to impute missing values on my *test* set, so I can't just use the `transform` method.

Instead, I created a function that I wanted to pass into the `apply` method, which can be seen here:

```
def fill_MSZoning(row):
    if row['MSZoning'] == 'C':
        return 69.7
    elif row['MSZoning'] == 'FV':
        return 59.49
    elif row['MSZoning'] == 'RH':
        return 58.92
    elif row['MSZoning'] == 'RL':
        return 74.68
    else:
        return 52.4
```

I call the function like this:

```
test['LotFrontage'] = test.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(fill_MSZoning), axis=1)
```

Now, the results for the `LotFrontage` column are the same as the `Id` column, even though I didn't specify this.

Any idea what is happening?

[image]

Comment: Instead of images, please post the data directly so others can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## creating dummy data
np.random.seed(100)

raw = {
    "group": np.random.choice("A B C".split(), 10),
    "value": [np.nan if np.random.rand()>0.8 else np.random.choice(100) for _ in range(10)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw)
display(df)

## calculate mean
means = df.groupby("group").mean()
display(means)
```

**Fill With Group Mean**

```py
## fill with mean value
def fill_group_mean(x):
    group_mean = means["value"].loc[x["group"].max()]
    return x["value"].mask(x["value"].isna(), group_mean)


r= df.groupby("group").apply(fill_group_mean)
r.reset_index(level=0)
```

**Output**

```
group   value
0   A   NaN
1   A   24.0
2   A   60.0
3   C   9.0
4   C   2.0
5   A   NaN
6   C   NaN
7   B   83.0
8   C   91.0
9   C   7.0



group   value
0   A   42.00
1   A   24.00
2   A   60.00
5   A   42.00
7   B   83.00
3   C   9.00
4   C   2.00
6   C   27.25
8   C   91.00
9   C   7.00
```